# SQL Report Builder 3.0 - How to group to get results (screenshots)

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-grouping

Here is the result set I want to get (from old report): Customer parameter is set to `select all`, in case anyone had questions about that field.
[image]
[image]

.....

[image]

As you can see, the report works so that each customer is grouped under a given salesperson and a total tally is at the bottom.

My problem is that this is the result I keep getting when trying to replicate this result in my new report (values aside, I know I can clean those up in the properties):

[image]

How do I do the grouping so that my subtotals, per customer, are reflected in a grand total at the bottom (in yellow)? I can do this easily in SQL, but getting it to work in report builder is what's driving me nuts lol

Comment: Looks like you are grouping at the customer and not the Sales Rep.

Comment: I'll have to trust your assessment. Can you refer me to a clear, no nonsense tutorial for grouping?

Comment: Start here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I do appreciate your time, but I find that the MS documentation is extraordinarily tedious and often difficult to understand.